# jQuery multidimensional array definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var questions = {}; 
for (var i = 0; i < tmp_questions.length; i++) {
    questions[i]["questions"] = tmp_questions[i];
    questions[i]["input_type_id"] = tmp_question_types[i];
    questions[i]["choices"] = tmp_choices[i];
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'questions' of undefined

How can  i define that multidimensional array ? 
I tried like `var questions = [];` but it does not work too...

Comment: Why is this tagged `jQuery`? May the `jQuery` tag be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is an array of objects:

```
// this should be an array
var questions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tmp_questions.length; i++) {
    // for each iteration, create an object and fill it
    questions[i] = {};
    questions[i]["questions"] = tmp_questions[i];
    questions[i]["input_type_id"] = tmp_question_types[i];
    questions[i]["choices"] = tmp_choices[i];
}
```

or in a clear way like this:

```
// this should be an array
var questions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tmp_questions.length; i++) {
    // for each iteration, push an object like so
    questions.push({
        "questions":     tmp_questions[i],
        "input_type_id": tmp_question_types[i],
        "choices":       tmp_choices[i]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to initialize the object first. Just write

```
questions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tmp_questions.length; i++) {
    questions[i] = {};
    questions[i]["questions"] = tmp_questions[i];
    questions[i]["input_type_id"] = tmp_question_types[i];
    questions[i]["choices"] = tmp_choices[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there with several corrections.

Error 1 :

```
var questions = {};
```

That is an object declaration. Not array.

Error 2 :

```
questions[i]["questions"]
```

To do that you must have an object at position `i` of `questions`.

So after corrections,

```
var questions = [];  //declare arry
for (var i = 0; i < tmp_questions.length; i++) {
    questions.push({}); //push it
    questions[i]["questions"] = tmp_questions[i]; // add properties
    questions[i]["input_type_id"] = tmp_question_types[i];
    questions[i]["choices"] = tmp_choices[i];

}
```

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Ahh.. my bad for the typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize before inserting.
Check this

```js
var tmp_choices= tmp_question_types = tmp_questions = [1,2,3,4,5];

var questions = [];  // If you want questions to be array of objects then use []

for (var i = 0; i < tmp_questions.length; i++) {
questions[i] = {};
    questions[i]["questions"] = tmp_questions[i];
    questions[i]["input_type_id"] = tmp_question_types[i];
    questions[i]["choices"] = tmp_choices[i];
}
console.log(questions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your object into your array before pushing data into it :

```
    var questions = []; // here is an array
    for (var i = 0; i < tmp_questions.length; i++) {
        questions[i] = {}; // here is an empty object
        questions[i]["questions"] = tmp_questions[i];
        questions[i]["input_type_id"] = tmp_question_types[i];
        questions[i]["choices"] = tmp_choices[i];
    }
```

actually you could do :

```
var questions = [];
for(...){
    questions[i] = {
        questions : tmp_questions[i],
        "input_type_id" : tmp_question_types[i],
        choices :  tmp_choices[i]
    }
}
```

Hope that help,
Paul J

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not a [Multi-dimensional Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Multi-dimensional_arrays), but just an array of objects.
A multidimensional array should be one like:

```
var bidimensionalArray = new Array(new Array());
var tridimensionalName = new Array(new Array(new Array()));
```

Anyway, in order to create an array that could contains an object with: "questions, ids and choices", you have to initialize every element of the array.

See following please:

```js
var tmp_questions = ["test1", "test2"];
var tmp_question_types = ["type1", "type2"];
var tmp_choices = ["choice1", "choice2"];


var questions = new Array(); 
for (var i = 0; i < tmp_questions.length; i++) {
    questions[i] = {};
    questions[i]["questions"] = tmp_questions[i];
    questions[i]["input_type_id"] = tmp_question_types[i];
    questions[i]["choices"] = tmp_choices[i];
}

console.log(questions);
```

I hope it helps you, bye.